# CSS not rendered on a dynamic smarty template element

Tags: css, smarty, smarty2

I have a dynamic span with dynamic class in my smarty template. The problem here is that the CSS assigned to those classes are not rendered. Everything works if I set things to static but when changed to dynamic it will not work anymore. I'm guessing the CSS is loaded first before the elements are rendered. What would be a good workaround for this?

Smarty:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="word">
    {counter start=9 print=false}
    {foreach from=$currentUser item=name}
        <span class="{counter}">{$name}</span>
    {/foreach}
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS that is not rendered:

```
#word span.l0 {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
#word span.l1 {
  animation-delay: 0.375s;
}
#word span.l2 {
  animation-delay: 0.75s;
}
#word span.l3 {
  animation-delay: 1.125s;
}
#word span.l4 {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
```

Comment: Please provide us with some print screen, what your generated HTML looks like.

Comment: The elements are displayed correctly but the styles are not attached to the elements. I've checked using inspect element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this HTML code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="word">
        {foreach from=$currentUser item=name key=i}
            <span class="span.l{i}">
                {$name}
            </span>
        {/foreach}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks